# Add column to View without using ALTER TABLE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `CTE`, something like

```
CREATE VIEW someView AS WITH foo AS (
    SELECT id FROM bar
        JOIN ...
), foo2 AS (
    SELECT whatever FROM bar2 ...
), ... AS ( ...
), lastResult AS (
   ...
) SELECT * FROM lastResult;
```

I want to add an `id column` to the last `SELECT` Statement (`SELECT * FROM lastResult;`). On an existing table you would do it like this

```
ALTER TABLE lastResult ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

Is that possible with a `CTE` and a `View`?

Comment: Do you mean you want a unique key in the lastResult?

Comment: @MiladDastanZand Yes I do. By creating one, not by selecting one from another result like `foo` or `foo2`

Comment: I think you can use row numbers, I write a simple sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the ROW_NUMBER.
here is a sample

```
CREATE VIEW someView AS WITH foo AS (
    SELECT id FROM bar
        JOIN ...
), foo2 AS (
    SELECT whatever FROM bar2 ...
), ... AS ( ...
), lastResult AS (
   ...
) SELECT * ,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY Your_Column) as Id
FROM
FROM lastResult;
```

Comment: It works, but it makes my query really very slow...

Comment: Yes, it is based on your rows count and can be slow, this side effect is unvoidable it is possible to get better performance, you can check the Your_Column that is used in order by clause, you may need to create an index on it.

Comment: @Stophface: if you "just" need a unique number but without any guaranteed order, you can use `row_number() over ()` which should make that faster.